# How do I parse and split data in single quotation mark using Java?

Tags: java, regex

So I have data in the format

```
['first data','second data', 'third data']
```

I need to extract each data in single quotation mark:

```
first data  
second data  
third data
```

I tried doing this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:^|\\s)'([^']*?)'(?:$|\\s)", Pattern.MULTILINE);  
Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
```

But it did not work. It says it could not find matches.

Comment: I used this but did not work:   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:^|\\s)'([^']*?)'(?:$|\\s)", Pattern.MULTILINE);  
Matcher m = p.matcher(data);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes from `java.util.regex` package. Something like this :

```
String data = "['first data','second data', 'third data']";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'(.*?)'");

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Output:

```
first data
second data
third data
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
   String values = "['first data','second data', 'third data']";
   String[] valuesArray = values.replaceAll("\\[|\\]|\\'","").split("\\,");
   for(String text:valuesArray)
        System.out.println(text);
```